# Ошибка при подключении к SQL server

Tags: android, sql-server, jdbc

Пишу приложение на андроид. На компе стоит SQL Server express. при подключении к серверу вылетает приложение с ошибкой : Драйверу не удалось установить безопасное соединение с SQL server, используя шифрование SSL. Ошибка: "Socket is closed". Ежу понятно что закрыт сокет. Как его открыть и надо ли вообще, может что-то в настройках сервера поменять? На сервере разрешено TCP IP соединение, порт добавлен в брандмауэр. Буду признателен за помощь

### активность:

```
package com.example.conference.activity

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.conference.R
import com.example.conference.adapter.ViewPagerAdapter
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.net.Socket
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.SQLDataException

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mainVP.adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        mainVP.offscreenPageLimit = 3
        mainTL.setupWithViewPager(mainVP)

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver").newInstance()
        } catch (e: ClassNotFoundException ) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        try {
            GlobalScope.launch {
                val url = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxx;databaseName=conference;user=user;password=user"
                val con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user", "user")
                val statement = con.createStatement()
                statement.close()
                con.close()
            }
        } catch(e: SQLDataException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

### Ошибка:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Драйверу не удалось установить безопасное соединение с SQL Server, используя шифрование SSL. Ошибка: "Socket is closed". ClientConnectionId:b1a53373-0831-4098-b9ad-a08de1d163df
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3155)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1912)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2709)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2363)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2214)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1275)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:861)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
at com.example.conference.activity.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:35)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:373)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:224)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1820)
... 14 more

Comment: сервер MS SQL? трейс ошибки в студию код в студию.

Comment: Да, MS. Добавил код

Comment: порт открыт точно? авторизация MS SQL не виндовая включена? попробуй с другого пк подключиться через мендежмент студию.

Comment: порт открыт. Сейчас переставил проверку подлинности на windows и sql, но не помогло. Возможности с другого пк подключится нет

Comment: Может как то можно отключить SSL шифрование?

Comment: не нужно хостнейм верифайр замнить в фабрике сокетов, и как-то соединению подсунуть. чтобы оно любой сертификат принимало.

Comment: MS SQL использует самоподписный сертификат, доверия у андроида ему нет. вот оно и не коннектиться.

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/jdbc-connections-fails-with-quot-the-driver-could-not-establish/ba-p/414157

Comment: + "encrypt=true;"
                + "trustServerCertificate=false;" попробуй этими опциями поиграть.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло

Comment: Значит у тебя проблема в различиях версий TLS у клиента и сервера. с encrypt = false тоже не заработало?

Comment: вообще зачем тебе с приложения прямой коннект к SQL? так обычно не делают.

Comment: нет, не помогло. Я по разному менял свойства и все равно socket is closed

Comment: Проект заключается в создании приложения с чатами и видеосвязью. Это в универе проект. Я в серверных делах вообще не шарю. Сервер для передачи и храения сообщений нужен. Сначала посоветовали postgresql, ничо не вышло, предложили ms sql expres

Comment: ну у андроида есть для этих дел FireBase, подружить андроида с MS SQL напрямую это из разряда мазахизма, т.к. оно потом на половине старых девайсов работать не будет. обычно всегда есть посредник, т.е. каконить REST с http(s), которое уже проксирует коннект к БД. если тебе нужен чат, то на MS SQL будет сложнее и не принято его выкидывать портами в интернет напрямую. или делай рест, или смотри в сторону файрбейза.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень хочется бросить универ, когда понимаешь, что драйвер от Microsoft, который постоянно поддерживается, не пашет, а драйвер, поддержку которого прекратили 7 лет назад прекрасно решает твои задачи. Используйте JTDS.